# Discord.py В каких файлах и с помощью каких систем реализовать базу данных?

Tags: python, json, база-данных, discord, ini

Мне нужно узнать, как сделать хорошую базу данных для своего `Discord Бота`, а именно: Какую систему для этого использовать? Какие файлы использовать как БД? Нужно чтобы в неё можно было быстро записывать много информации и быстро читать эту информацию, а также желательно чтобы её можно было совместить с сайтом, который будет записывать информацию для этого `бота`(ID серверов, префиксы, пользовательские команды и т.п.).

В данный момент использую: `.py`(в случаях когда нужно записать в переменную функцию), `.ini`, `.json`
Для их чтения использую: `ConfigParser` для `.ini` файлов, `JSON` для `.json` файлов.

Какая из этих 3 систем лучше(более быстрая скорость обработки больших объёмов информации: как чтение, так и запись)? Нужно ли вообще использовать другие системы? В каком случае, какая система лучше справляется?

Comment: Яндекс.поиск  "база данных' выбирай по твоим кретерия

Answer (score 1):

sql попробуй

снизу оставил тебе кликабельный текст, юзай поможет

[Пользуйся](https://www.google.com/)